# Is it possible to access a json array element without using index number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
   "responseObject": {
   "name": "ObjectName",
   "fields": [
   {
     "fieldName": "refId",
     "value": "2170gga35511"
   },
   {
     "fieldName": "telNum",
     "value": "4541885881"
   }]}
}
```

I want to access `"value"` of the the array element with `"fieldName": "telNum"` without using index numbers, because I don't know everytime exactly at which place this `telNum` element will appear.

What I dream of is something like this:

*jsonVarName*.responseObject.fields['fieldname'='telNum'].value

Is this even possible in JavaScript?

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.find()` - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: @AlonEitan I don't doubt there's a duplicate, but I don't think that's it.

Comment: @Pointy. Thanks. Vote retracted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - get the value of a property within a specific JSON array element by its key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901043/javascript-get-the-value-of-a-property-within-a-specific-json-array-element-by)

Comment: If you are in control of generating the JSON, I would suggest you pick a different layout, and use the fieldName-value as an objectKey instead of an array value.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson that question never came up during my searches... sorry. and you are right, seems to be close to mine; I just defined what I expected clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
var k={
   "responseObject": {
   "name": "ObjectName",
   "fields": [
   {
     "fieldName": "refId",
     "value": "2170gga35511"
   },
   {
     "fieldName": "telNum",
     "value": "4541885881"
   }]
}};
value1=k.responseObject.fields.find(
function(i)
{return (i.fieldName=="telNum")}).value;
console.log(value1);
```

Comment: thanks, I believe this is the closest solution that is available.

Comment: Make sure you won't break anything in old browsers

Comment: @ArseniProkharchyk thanks for the warning, but this code is just for a demonstration and there won't even be a browser in place :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.. Native JavaScript has nothing similar to XPATH like in xml to iterate through JSON. You have to loop or use `Array.prototype.find()` as stated in comments.
It's experimental and supported only Chrome 45+, Safari 7.1+, FF 25+. No IE.

Example can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Can you elaborate and maybe give a small example?

Comment: What example would you like me to write? Not sure I understand what you want to see.. Loop? Array.prototype.find? xml XPATH?

Comment: Just show OP how to use `find` or an alternative and give a little information about the support for said method.

Comment: do not provide links to external sites as answers, those are not considered answers

Comment: The question was "Is this even possible in JavaScript?". I gave my answer. Then, people asked for an example. I provided an example, not considering it as answer, but as a help to find what they are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) that lets you write queries just like XPATH does for XML.

```
$.store.book[*].author  the authors of all books in the store
$..author               all authors
$.store.*               all things in store, which are some books and a red bicycle.
$.store..price          the price of everything in the store.
$..book[2]              the third book
$..book[(@.length-1)] 
$..book[-1:]            the last book in order.
$..book[0,1]
$..book[:2]             the first two books
$..book[?(@.isbn)]      filter all books with isbn number
$..book[?(@.price<10)]  filter all books cheapier than 10
$..*                    All members of JSON structure.
```

Comment: Have to admit, I didn't know about the lib. Though it adds you one more dependancy to your code.. If you are ok with that - do that! Thanks for the lib.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to loop through and find it.

```js
var json = {
   "responseObject": {
   "name": "ObjectName",
   "fields": [
   {
     "fieldName": "refId",
     "value": "2170gga35511"
   },
   {
     "fieldName": "telNum",
     "value": "4541885881"
   }]
};
  
function getValueForFieldName(fieldName){
  for(var i=0;i<json.fields.length;i++){
    if(json.fields[i].fieldName == fieldName){
      return json.fields[i].value;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(getValueForFieldName("telNum"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a better option to modify the array into object with `fieldName` as keys once to avoid using `.find` over and over again.

```
fields = Object.assign({}, ...fields.map(field => {
    const newField = {};
    newField[field.fieldName] = field.value;
    return newField;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean and easy way to just loop through array.

```
var json = {
   "responseObject": {
   "name": "ObjectName",
   "fields": [
    {
     "fieldName": "refId",
     "value": "2170gga35511"
    },
  {
    "fieldName": "telNum",
    "value": "4541885881"
  }]
 }   
  $(json.responseObject.fields).each(function (i, field) {
    if (field.fieldName === "telNum") {

      return field.value // break each
    }
  })
```

Comment: thanks, but I was looking for a pure javascript solution without jquery.